# I "was eating food" and "scrolling my phone", and I found that the teacher was calling me - past continuous to provide the background info?

Tags: tense, usage

Can we use continuous tense to provide some background information before we talk about other things?

**Example 1**

> A: What happened?

> B: I **was watching** a movie, and my mom called me, and my brother also knocked on the door, and I got shocked so bad that I almost fainted.

**Example 2**

> A: How did that happen?

> B: I **was eating** food and **scrolling** my phone, and I found that the teacher was calling me.

Comment: [scrolling *on* my phone//was shocked, not "got shocked": that would be electrical only]

Comment: Yes, you can - but a native speaker would say _I was eating my lunch/a sandwich_ or just _I was eating_.

Comment: "scrolling my phone" doesn't sound fluent.  "Scrolling **through** my phone" is a more fluent phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use *and* as your conjunction and switch from the continuous tense, you create the feeling that a subsequent activity, instead of a concurrent activity, might have occurred.

If you want to express concurrency, it is best to use a conjunction that also expresses concurrency or use the continuous tense after *and*.

> *I was eating and scrolling on my phone **when** I noticed the teacher was calling on me.*

Now you have three things happening at the same time - *eating, scrolling, and noticing.*

To use *and* and preserve the concurrency you would say,

> *I was eating lunch, scrolling on my phone, **and** noticing the teacher was calling on me.*

In this case you have three concurrent activities.

Comment: scroll on a phone, not scroll a phone